Manga about a female master mistreating a male disciple, then he gained demonic powers and killed her
About a month a go, I read this manga, but now it's nowhere to be found. It's ongoing and the last chapter I read was 8.
She is a master that has only one disciple. She mistreated him. He gained demonic powers and killed her. Somehow, they both got reincarnated and the master is trying to save herself.
The cover of it looks like this: purple background. The disciple is wearing black and is holding her. She's wearing white. She always used to wear white, but after reincarnation, she wore a light green robe.

Do you remember or have any idea whether it was a manga (Japanese), manhwa (Korean) or manhua (Chinese)? Was it a webtoon (meant for vertical scrolling) or intended for print (panels laid out on pages)? Any other distinguishing features about the characters? You mention the colour of the characters' clothes do you remember their hair colour or any other notable features?

I think it was manhua and webtoon.the fl had dark brown hair I assume. I read it on book mangabut now it's not there anymore.
Also thank you for your help
